# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/followme/signupscript.php on line 12

Tags: php, html, css, helper

Can someone share where i went wrong?
It Says This When Im Refreshing The Page In The Browerser (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/followme/signupscript.php on line 12) But My Query variable is good;

```
<?php include "config.php" ?>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $_POST['password2'];
    $email = $_POST['email']

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="$username"");
    $check_username = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $check_username2 = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($check_username == 1) {
        echo "Someone AlreadeHas That name";
    } else {
        echo "working";
    }
}
?>
```

---

config.php file

```
<?php

// Connect To Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("followme");

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using double quotes where you need single quotes.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="$username"");
```

should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
```

**AND**

You're missing a semi-colon, too:

```
 $email = $_POST['email'] //<-- here
```

Comment: Thats Not The Problem? just Tried

Comment: Thanks I just Got It Working It Was The Semicolon. Thank So So Much!